# How do I update a model in ASP.NET MVC LINQ to SQL from another object?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

How do I update a model in ASP.NET using [LINQ to SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query#LINQ_to_SQL)?

In Ruby on Rails we'd do this:

```
@record1 = Record.find(id) #Get the record
@record1.update_attributes(record2) #Data from record2 is copied to record1
```

And it generates an SQL update statement.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, Record record)
{
    //How would I do it in LINQ here?
}
```

The closest I have come is manually copying all the fields over, that is:

```
record1.name = record2.name
record1.something = record2.something
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the following 2 methods:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470185.aspx

```
UpdateModel(record)
_service.Save()
```

And: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.tryupdatemodel.aspx

```
if (TryUpdateModel(record))
   _service.Save()
```

TryUpdateModel method is like the UpdateModel method except it does not throw an exception if the updated model state is not valid.

Comment: I've "merged" both your answers into this one - you may delete the other.

Comment: Although they say that rails is all smoke and mirrors.. but i found the whole ValueProvider thing to be much more confusing!